# Can we get property of Sytem across different context

Tags: java, glassfish

I have two different context or modules. In one context, I set a property using `System.setProperty`. Assume both context are deployed on same application server and also once property set from one context then and then second context will be accessed. So in this case can I able to get value of those properties in second context?

Comment: Add other tags also, please :)

Comment: ok.but which other tag i should add because it's related to only java.could you please suggest me another tag if I am missing

Comment: `same application server` Which application server are you using? :)

Comment: I am using glassfish server however i believe that it's not dependent on server that's why i didn't mention.please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Adding tags gets people's attention. If there are people who are interested in `glassfish` tag, your question will be highlighted to them. Get it? Allows for quicker response. :)

Comment: Please note that not all of the system properties can be changed. The `setProperty()` runs w/o any errors but it will be idempotent...

Comment: @rlegendi:sorry but really I didn't get your point

Comment: You cannot change the system property classpath for instance. Another thing is the `user.home` you cannot change with `System.setProperty()`.